# How can I get the gap between A time and B time?

Tags: java, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I want get the durations gap of two videos contain milliseconds.

A : 01:18:19.92, B : 01:18:19.57

```
public String calTime(String A, String B) {

  String sFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS";
  SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(sFormat);

  try {

    Date A1 = dFormat.parse(A);
    Date A2 = dFormat.parse(B);

    //A1 = Thu Jan 01 01:18:19 KST 1970
    //A1.getTime() = -27700943
    //A2 = Thu Jan 01 01:18:19 KST 1970
    //A2.getTime() = -27701000

    System.out.println(A1.getTime() - A2.getTime());

  } catch (ParseException ex) {}

}
```

1. Why are the values from `getTime()` negative? Cause I didn't define yy-MM-dd the Date method?
2. Can I get and calculation durations like HH:mm:ss.SSS using Date method? I don't need year, month, day, etc.
3. how can I normal gap of two durations?

Comment: Tip: Consider using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for [durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS ` to avoid ambiguity with time-of-day values. The standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why appear minus front of getTime() values? Cause I didn't define yy-MM-dd the Date method?

Because the dates are before Jan 1st 1970 at midnight **GMT**. You're clearly in a GMT+XX:XX timezone, so although they're after 1970 in that timezone, they aren't in GMT.

> Cause I didn't define yy-MM-dd the Date method?

Yes, indirectly. `SimpleDateFormat` assumes midnight Jan 1st 1970 GMT if there is no date portion.

> Can I get and calculation durations like HH:mm:ss.SSS using Date method?

Java's original `Date` object is not very useful. JDK 8 adds the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package with more useful classes in it, including [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

> how can I normal gap of two durations?

That's what your code is currently doing. It's getting the interval (gap) in milliseconds. It's a positive number because you're doing A - B, and A is later than B. You can turn that number into a `Duration` via [`Duration.ofMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofMillis-long-) if desired:

```
long interval = A1.getTime() - A2.getTime();
System.out.println("interval in ms: " + interval);
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis(interval);
System.out.println("duration: " + d);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/vbSllC)

...though just for formatting it doesn't buy you much, I'm not immediately seeing anything in [`java.time.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) that formats `Duration`s or `TemporalAmount`s.

Comment: Thank you Crowder really good answer!!. I will try using Duration.ofMillis :)

Comment: Indeed, no duration formatter in package `java.time.format`. For that purpose, people have to write their own workarounds (not always easy) or use external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

## `java.time.Duration`

Since Java 8:
Why not using `Duration.between(Temporal startInclusive, Temporal endExclusive)`

```
Duration tempDuration = Duration.between(A1.toInstant(), A2.toInstant());
System.out.println(tempDuration.toMillis());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html

> The result can be negative if the first date is after the second.
>
> Can also use `LocalTime` instead of date

Comment: Your Answer is a good start, but is incomplete. The Question aims a generating a String in a particular format. Hint: Java 9 and later (not Java 8), `Duration.to…Part` methods.